# How to control the Kendo Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do I control how many rows appear in a kendo grid?  Real Estate is limited, so I need to have a lot of info in a pretty compact space.  I'm trying to pack everything in my grid in a 300-pixel high area.

The issue I'm having is that all 200-plus rows of data that are being returned from my MVC JsonResult in my controller are displaying at once, on a single page.  Not quite exactly what I'm looking for.

Code is below, if someone a little more knowledgeable about formatting a kendo grid could help out, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

-RC

{}

```
        var RemoteJsonData_Call = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport:
            {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: resourceURL_Call
                },
                pageSizes: 8,
                serverPaging: true
            },

            schema: {
                model: {
                    ScheduleData: {
                        extensionDataField: {
                            fields: {
                                ScheduleDate: { type: "date" },
                                ScheduleAmount: { type: "number" },
                                SchedulePrice: { type: "number" },
                                ScheduleNotes: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        $('#callSched').kendoGrid({
            height: '300',
            sortable: true,
            reorderable: true,
            resizable: true,
            pageable: {
                numeric: true,
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                previousNext: true,
                input: true,
                info: true
            },
            columns: [
               {
                   field: "ScheduleDate",
                   title: "Date",
                   template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(ScheduleDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy'), 'MM-dd-yyyy') #"
               },
                {
                    field: "ScheduleAmount",
                    title: "Amount",
                },
                {
                    field: "SchedulePrice",
                    title: "Price"
                },
                {
                    field: "ScheduleNotes",
                    title: "Notes"
                }
            ], dataSource: RemoteJsonData_Call
        });
```

{}

Comment: someone else may know how to do this via kendo.  We just looked at the rendered output and found the main tag and adjusted the size using css manually.  Not pretty but it worked

Comment: It's not so much the *size* that's the problem.  I The initial response displays EVERY row in the response.  When I click the paging controls in the chrome, everything acts like its supposed to and settles down inside the allotted container - but when the control first renders, there are data rows spilling outside the container, behind other controls, to the end of the data.  its wierd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have server paging and page size set up incorrectly here:

```
    var RemoteJsonData_Call = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport:
        {
            read: {
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: resourceURL_Call
            },
            pageSizes: 8,
            serverPaging: true
        },
```

It should be:

```
    var RemoteJsonData_Call = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport:
        {
            read: {
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: resourceURL_Call
            }
        },
        pageSize: 8,
        serverPaging: true
```

The config options were in the wrong place, and "pageSizes" was misspelled, it should be "pageSize" with no "s" on the end.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-pageSize

Comment: I wish I could mark TWO answers here... both OnaBai and CodingWithSpike had parts of it:

OnaBai recommended that I remove the serverPaging declaration, and CodingWithSpike showed me that I had everything in the wrong place.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have defined that the paging is done in the server when it is not. You should say:

```
serverPaging: false
```

or just nothing since the default value is `false`.

With this you should have a grid with the number of pixels specified in the `height` option (in your example 300 pixels). Other options in you example are correct.